# How to prove the ownership of a public Git/GitHub repo?

Tags: git, github

How can I **clearly prove to other persons** (for example very picky employers) that I'm the creator of a public GitHub repo (beside avatar pictures etc.)?

Does Git have something like a key file that proves the authencity of a repo or is there a best practice for doing so?

Comment: What are you trying to prove -- that an account belongs to you, or that wrote a piece of code?

Comment: Good point! In this case, the "owner"/account owner of a repo wants to prove his ownership to others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add a signed tag to the repository.

This is a gpg signature, so it can be cryptographically verified.  I wrote about [how to go about it here](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/2796779828/signing-a-git-tag)

Answer (score 1):

I'd add your open-source projects on Github to a [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) profile. That way they're all verified through the authentication process and you can show off all of your other work. Yes, this is a bit of a shameless plug

Comment: @Panique I have an invite I can send you if you want

Answer (score 0):

How picky are they?

I would think the first thing to try is to show them the very first commit. It's normally a git object you can't remove from the history so it should show your address email and/or name.

If it's not enough, you can probably show the the public key on your machine and the public key registered on Github is the same?

Third theory, maybe just ask Github support? They may have more internal history that may be useful.

Comment: Public keys are that: public. Any GitHub employee, and many a system's administrator, can access your public key. You could show you have the *private* key (or just the password).

Answer (score 0):

For example (and guessing by the account names and avatar pictures!), perhaps you want to demonstrate that you're the creator of one of https://github.com/panique's repositories.

One interpretation of that is that you want to demonstrate that you control the *panique* GitHub account.  There's at least a couple of ways of doing that:

- Log into the account in front of them.  But you may not be comfortable doing that; it's asking a bit much really, especially if it's on their network.
- Demonstrate that you can make a change that they requested to the account.  For example, you could temporarily put a phrase of their choosing into the Company or Location fields of your profile; or do something that appears on your Public Activity: star a repository of their choice, perhaps.

Another interpretation would be that you want to demonstrate that it really was you who did something back in the history of the repository: e.g., that it was you who made a bunch of the commits.  In this case, you're in the realm of GPG signed tags, etc; c.f. @Abizem's answer.

Comment: He, no, in this case i'm part of the employer's team. So i'm on the *bad* side. I didn't wrote this in the question to avoid a you-dont-trust-people shitstorm. But yes, that's my github account.